# Function returning the set of sets which are no superset of each other

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Given a set $S$ of sets.
Assume a function $f$ which removes all supersets of any set in $S$.

Example:
$f(\{\{ a\}, \{ a,b\}, \{ a, b,c\}, \{ b,c\},\{ b,c,d\} \}) = \{\{ a\}, \{ b,c\} \}$

Does this function have any particular commonly known name? Or the resulting set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting set, it seems, is the collection of $\subseteq$-minimal elements from $S$.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks!